# How to create a map puts numbers in order

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Hi I'm looking to create a map in node.js where I'm able to put numbers in ranking order so for example `14, 10 and 5` in a list order where #1 takes the highest number and #3 the lowest number For example:

| Rank | Numer |
| --- | --- |
| #1 | 14 |
| #2 | 10 |
| #3 | 5 |

As you can see I'm wanting 14 the largest number therefore rank #1 and so forth.I'm going to be fetching my numbers from table in postgres.

My SQL query looks like this:

`pool.query('SELECT total_xp FROM levels WHERE guild_id = $1 AND user_id = $2', [message.guild.id, member.id])`

If anyone can help me on how I can achieve this help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your SQL query look like? Shouldn't you be able to simply add `ORDER BY number DESC`?

Comment: I've added my sql query to my question ideally a map would return 1 if the number is 14 for example.

Comment: What map exactly? And why not add an `ORDER BY` in the SQL?

Comment: I could do that but then I would need to determine whether the highest number in the query as #1 as in if  the highest number in the query is 14 then return the number 1 and so forth